# Can we Implement ReactJs on a particular page of a website which is purely built on Javascript / Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, shopify, shopify-template

Have a query regarding ReactJs can we implement a small feature using ReactJs on a particular page of a website that is built mostly in pure javascript and Jquery ?.

For example, I am working on a website that has an

e-commerce platform implemented with Shopify, now I wanted to have a small feature using ReactJs.You can consider its a mini / micro app of Reactjs

Comment: I would think so. ReactDOM asks for a specific element to use as a root. This could be a small element somewhere on the page and not the whole page.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, just define the node where you want to render this micro app

Comment: actually, the thing is the whole website is built upon the liquid templating engine so I don't think we can access any node & even somehow we can target any div, where to include Javascript files in which there will be React?

Comment: The fact that Liquid templates are used on the server is irrelevant. You can render a React element into the the DOM. You can upload JS files to your Shopify theme under Theme > Edit Code > Assets > Add Asset.

(Explanation: Shopify servers are rendering the liquid templates to HTML strings (to be exact: binary streams with MIME type text/html, usually in UTF-8 encoding). After the browser receives a HTTP response, it creates javascript nodes for each HTML element and finally constructs the DOM.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, ReactJS is nothing but front-end code for your use case, so you can count on DOM existing when your ReactJS instantiates. So if your client/customer can afford the hit to the customer experience to download ReactJS to support your micro-function, there is no limit to what you can do with your JS. You may find it superior to just present your small feature in pure JS, to keep it tight and fast.